# Read Data from weighing machine in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter and i am trying to read data from weighing machine

How To Read Real Time Data From Weighing Machine In flutter Web Application

I searched but all code related to windows only but i need code for reading data in web level

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.